# how to test inApp purchase in debug mode flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

everyone testing inapp purchase in google play console closed test,i want to test IAP debug mode in flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can add your debug device (Not simulator) gmail address as tester , then your device will work on debug mode .

Go to your https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ Under 'Developer' Account/Settings/Account details/License Testing

https://medium.com/@monicacurti/faster-in-app-billing-subscriptions-testing-8e68551b4e2f