# Is it possible to run in app purchase debug mode on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, debugging, in-app-purchase

I integrated in-app purchases with the Flutter [in-app-purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) library. The app must be published in order to try the purchase. Therefore, I cannot test the application by putting a breakpoint in debug mode. Isn't there a way to try and debug the purchase?

Comment: Check this if it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705416/how-to-test-inapp-purchase-in-debug-mode-flutter

Comment: I can run purchases in debug mode by adding test user mail in the play store developer console. But how can I do this on iOS side? What I really want to ask is to be able to debug on the iOS side. What can I do for it?

Answer (score 1):

The app does need to be uploaded to the play store, but it does not need to be in production: internal release is enough. Afterwards, you'll be able to debug.
There are other steps to take on app store connect and play console before being able to do anything.
This tutorial has detailed intructions for every step: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0